# Native Camera app deleted on iPad mini

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, photo-booth

The native camera app on my iPad mini got deleted somehow. Also, I couldn't find it in the App Store to download. It happened on iOS 10.3. I just now upgraded to iOS 11.

The iPad also had Photo Booth app which is also invisible now. On the App Store, the app shows an open button next to Photo Booth app, but nothing happens upon tapping on it.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I don't think the Camera is a stock app that you can delete.  I can delete many stock apps on my iPhone with iOS 11 but Camera is not one of them.  It's not in the App Store, either.  Try searching for it.  It might have been moved to a folder or different screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like Camera is disabled in Settings > General > Restrictions. This removes the Camera and FaceTime apps. [A similar post on Apple's forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3624890?tstart=0) said that the Photo Booth app was removed by this restriction.

[This third-party article on an MDM tool](https://support.jamfnow.com/hc/en-us/articles/207526606-iOS-Device-Restrictions) says that the restriction removes the Photo Booth app:

> - **Disable Camera**
>
>   - The camera will be completely disabled. This also remove the Camera, Photobooth, and Facetime apps on the home screen.

It would make sense that the restriction available in the UI flips the same bit as the MDM restriction.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much. The camera is back now.